emacs-style yank and kill for the current line in insert mode
I'm trying to replicate the bash/emacs keybindings for neovim's command console and insert mode.

Problem:
Since <C-W> and <C-U> work by default I thought at first that I don't have to remap those keybindings. However it seems that the deleted text is not saved in any register, is this correct? To account for this I have the following mappings:
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '<C-U>', '<C-O>"+d0', { noremap = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '<C-W>', '<C-O>"+dB', { noremap = true })

But these keybindings have the problem that they never delete the last character (which is the character under the cursor in normal mode). How can I account for that?

Problem
In bash, subsequent backwards deleting of words will append it to the yank register. E.g. if I write Hello World and delete it with two subsequent <C-W> and then yank/paste, the result will be the same as using <C-U> to clear the line and then yank/paste. Is there a way to append to the register instead of overwriting it?




Instead of relying users of this site to be familiar with "emacs-style", please explain what you expect to happen. 2) Don't put tags in your question's title. 3) Please ask one question per question. Your problem 1 can easily be fixed with :help o_v.

